# how to use extended ASCII instead of unicode in PHP

Tags: php, visual-foxpro

I have an application that is developed in visual fox pro in which I have an encryption method that I want to transfer to php code, the code is as follows:

```
FUNCTION Encrypt
 LPARAMETER text
 LOCAL KEY, TEXT, J, LETTER
 key = ')&H%$V1#@^+=?/><:MN*-'
 textText = SPACE(0)
 c = 1
 FOR j = 1 TO LEN(text)
      letter = MOD(ASC(SUBSTR(text, j, 1))+ASC(SUBSTR(key, c, 1)), 256)
      teXtoenc = teXtoenc+CHR(letter)
      c = c+1
      IF c>=LEN(password)
           c = 1
      ENDIF
 ENDFOR
 RETURN text
ENDFUNC
```

the transformation in php would be:

```
<?php
function Encripta($teXto){
    $clAve = ")&H%\$V1#@^+=?/><:MN*-";
    $teXtoenc = "";
    $c = 1;
    for($j = 0; $j < strlen($teXto); $j++){
        $leTra = (odr($teXto[$j]) + ord($clAve[$c])) % 256;
        $c ++;
        $teXtoenc .= chr($leTra);
        if($c >= strlen($clAve))
            $c = 1;
    }
    return $teXtoenc;
}
?>
```

but when executing the code in php the results of both methods are not the same, investigating I found that reason is because php works with Unicode and not extended ASCII

Comment: Can you give a couple of specific examples of where it's different, please.

Comment: `$$clAve[$c]` what the purpose of this?

Comment: I made a mistake transcribing the code is $clAve[$c]

Comment: ADyson, okay. the php method returns |��������` and the visual fox pro method returns }¦v¥|šr§Š€

Comment: There's no such thing as "extended ASCII", and PHP does not care about encoding and will output exactly the bytes you tell it to. Whatever you're using to _view_ the results is using the incorrect encoding _for display_. You need to figure out what display encoding "visual fox pro" is using and apply that to whatever you're viewing the PHP output in. Probably ISO8859-1 or CP1252.

Comment: That said, viewing raw binary data as text is usually not a great idea to begin with as different programs will display unprintable byte values differently. Encode the output as something simpler/safer like hex or base64 if you just want to compare two binary outputs.

Answer (score 3):

It's an off by one error... In VFP the first character has the index 1. The following code gives you the first character of the password string:

```
SUBSTR(key,1,1)
```

PHP is zero based. The following code gives you the first character of the password string:

```
$clAve[0]
```

You are initializing the index for the password (`$clAve`) with 1 instead of 0. Therefore you end up encoding (can't call this encrypting) with a different byte in PHP compared to VFP. Here's a working version in PHP:

```
function Encripta($teXto){
    $clAve = ")&H%\$V1#@^+=?/><:MN*-";
    $teXtoenc = "";
    $c = 0;
    for($j = 0; $j < strlen($teXto); $j++){
        $leTra = (ord($teXto[$j]) + ord($clAve[$c])) % 256;
        $c ++;
        $teXtoenc .= chr($leTra);
        if($c >= strlen($clAve))
            $c = 0;
    }
    return $teXtoenc;
}
?>
```

Where you wrote `$c = 1;` I changed this to `$c = 0;`. The remaining code is unchanged.

The way you could have found this yourself is by printing the value of both ord() calls in PHP and the ASC() calls in VFP. The result for PHP would have been:

```
72 38 / 111 72 / 108 37 / 97 36
```

and in VFP it would have been

```
72 41 / 111 38 / 108 72 / 97 37
```

You notice how the second number, the character from the password, moved to the left in PHP, because you started with the second character in the string.